# What data should I sync to iCloud?

Tags: ios5, icloud

I have a question about what to sync to iCloud.

I have an application that downloads data from my server and stores it in core data. The user can then mark some of the data as favorites.

What's the best way to use iCloud?

1. Should I sync the complete core database, or
2. should I just sync the favorites using NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore (an NSArray with references to the favorites.)

Since the user can download the data again, my first thought was to use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore since the amount of data would be less. But I think it would be simpler to sync the core data.

The amount of data is at the moment less than 1 MB.

Any reflections are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that just syncing the favourites would make for the better solution, otherwise any changes in the data would mean extra headaches as there might be differing versions between what is synched to iCloud and what is on your server (although you made no further clarification as to the type of data).

Besides this possibility for inconsistency, is there any good reason to push the extra data to iCloud?

Comment: The datamodel is very basic and is based on one entity and consist of about 2500 records at the moment. The changes would mainly be new records but there could be changes in existing data. I have no good reason why I should push the extra data to iCloud. I think a normal user would end up with about 20 favorites. The only reason not to use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore is that the class reference says it should be used for settings references.

Comment: Or should I use two persistance store and save the favorites in that and sync to icloud? NSUbiquitosKeyValueStore doesn't feel right for the purpose